# How can I continually repeat first promise until second promise resolves?

Tags: javascript, promise, axios, es6-promise

So I've got a React App that creates a video, this is a very long api request taking between 1 and 10 minutes to resolve. I have a separate api call which I need to run continually every couple of seconds to check the status until the first promise is resolved (and the video is compiled).

```
        const promise1 = axios.post("/api/create", data);
        //promise1 takes between 1 and 10 minutes to resolve (video creation).

        const promise2 = axios.get(`/progress-${uniqueId}.txt`);
        // I need promise2 (which checks status of promise1) to continually run
        //at an interval (every 5 seconds?) until promise 1 resolves


        Promise.race([promise1, promise2]).then(res=>{
            //this obviously returns promise2 first, as expected, but 
            //once it comes back I need it to refire after 5 seconds
            //continually until promise 1 resolves
            console.log(res)});
    };
```

Any idea how I can recursively call Promise2 until Promise1 Resolves?

Comment: If you have control over the API, it would make a lot more sense for `/create` to resolve with the value you need, I would think, if possible, instead of creating two separate ones (with one running extremely frequently) for what only needs to be a single request

Comment: You could even use streams and dump the status every X seconds, on the same endpoint that's uploading the video.

Comment: @CertainPerformance A single endpoint is not enough if you want a progress bar in your UI. You need a second endpoint being called however often you want to update the progress bar to do this. Either that or use something event based like websockets

Answer (score 0):

Promises, by definition, are functions which return a value at most **once**, at a later point in time. You can't re-run a promise, the best you can do is recreate one using some factory pattern.

Alongside that, you need a mechanism to check if your create promise has been fulfilled.

```
// Send create request
const creationPromise = axios.post("/api/create", data);

// Track creationPromise state
let isCreated = false;
creationPromise.then(() => isCreated = true);

// factory for creating a new progress request on-demand
const progressFactory = () => axios.get(`/progress-${uniqueId}.txt`);

// While the created request hasn't completed, loop
while (!isCreated) {
   // Send new progress request
   const progress = await progressFactory();
   console.log("progress", progress);
}
// Done, create returned
console.log("Finished!");
```

Comment: Ideally this would be wrapped in a single closure so that multiple requests to create don't overwrite the global `isCreated` variable

Answer (score 0):

Well I have another approach. How about if instead of hanging there for up to ten minutes, send whatever is needed to the backend as soon as you get it send back a status of 202 = `The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 202 Accepted response status code indicates that the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed; in fact, processing may not have started yet. The request might or might not eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing actually takes place.` you don’t have to send the response at the end you can do it at any time by doing so you release the client while the server keeps processing.